# is it possible to set the contents (data) of a file upload input via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, blob

i am using html5 canvas to alter an image.  i would like to be able to use the resulting canvas image data to send to the server using the ***same file upload field***.  (alternately, it could be by adding a ***new field to the existing form***).

i have converted the image to a Blob, but it seems that the only way to send this type of data to the server is using FormData, which requires its own (separate) XMLHttpRequest.  this is not desirable for me.

(**context**: i am trying to essentially hijack any *arbitrary* file input field in any *arbitrary* form on a page.  consequently, i do not want to alter the method the form is submitted and i would also like to *avoid changing anything on the server side* as well.  basically, i think the only way to do this would be to re-use or replace the file field.  probably not possible, but i thought i would ask.)

Comment: I don't really understand your requirements.  If you can hijack any form then you're going to have to change every form submission target to deal with this additional image data.  Sending the image via a separate AJAX request seems a lot simpler.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  this is exactly what i am trying to avoid, adding _additional_ information.   for example, if the form has a single field (type file) called **foobar**, then i want there to just end up, as far as the server is concerned, a POST with only a single field **foobar** with the contents of the canvas image in it.

this is essentially what happens with the FormData ajax post, but i dont want to have to clone the entire original form (to get all the data) and risk messing with things like onSubmit verifications and who knows what else the original form might do.