# Access html form element from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file, input

Can a file type input element of an html form be updated using Javascript? As in my case I generate an image object  which I want to assign to the input field of type file.  Just like we assign the text fields of an input form from Javascript can we also update file input from Javascript? My image object of type png is stored in a variable that I want to assign to the input field.

Comment: So you want to upload Javascript data, not the contents of an actual file?

Comment: Here's a 3-year-old question that asks a similar question, it has no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482391/is-it-possible-to-set-the-contents-data-of-a-file-upload-input-via-javascript?rq=1

Comment: I actually generate a png image from a canvas. And this image is stored in a variable. Now I want to assign this image element to the input.

Comment: So it's exactly the same question, since he also used a canvas.

Comment: And here's an unanswered question that asks how to do it using AJAX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230665/upload-image-data-as-a-file-w-o-file-input-control

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not set the value of inputs of type file. It would be a security risk, since it would allow you to upload any file from the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax with a FormData object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects gives you an overview of the API.

Comment: This seems very helpful!

Comment: thanks my main aim was to send an image  generated in png format using form data by appending it and sending data in multipart format

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Ajax.
You need to extract the image data from the canvas and convert it into a Blob object. Then you append it to a FormData object and send that with an Ajax request.

I wrote a working example on how it works:

```
<?
    // handle upload
    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        file_put_contents('data', serialize($_POST));
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['name']);
        die;
    }
    $data = array();
    if (file_exists('data'))
        $data = unserialize(file_get_contents('data'));
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CANVAS Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Uploaded:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Image: <img src="<?=file_exists('image.png')?'image.png':''?>"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                Name: <?=isset($data['name'])?$data['name']:''?>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Form:</h3>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Image: <canvas data-name="image" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button>Upload</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            var form = document.querySelector("form");
            var canvas = form.querySelector("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.fillStyle = "#E0E0E0";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
            ctx.fill();

            canvas.onclick = function(e) { // modify canvas by drawing circles
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+Math.floor(128+Math.random()*128)+",0,0)";;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                ctx.fill();
            };
            function canvasToBlob(canvas) { // extract the image data and convert it to a Blob object
                var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
                var array = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
                }
                return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
            }
            form.onsubmit = function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var form_data = new FormData(this); // create a FormData object and pass it the form element to fill it with form data
                form_data.append("image", canvasToBlob(canvas), "image.png"); // add image data from canvas

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", window.location.href, true);
                xhr.onload = function(e) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        console.log(this.responseText);
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                };
                xhr.send(form_data); // send the FormData object
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```